# Magento 2 filter_condition_callback

Tags: adminhtml, magento-2.1, grid, filter, uicomponent

How can I perform the same logic of **filter_condition_callback** of Magento 1 in Magento 2

I have a country column which I save comma separated values in db I have managed to create the filter but I am not able to get the result the values are stored comma separated.

How can I apply **filter_condition_callback** to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it same as magento1, inside grid.php file,

You can reference for used of `filter_conditions_callback` from core file,

```
magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Crosssell.php
```

Now set inside `grid.php` file

```
class Grid{
      //logic for class...
        $this->addColumn(
                    'position',
                    [
                        'header' => __('Position'),
                        'name' => 'position',
                        'type' => 'number',                
                        'index' => 'position',               
                        'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, 'filterCustom']
                    ]
                );

        public function filterCustom($collection, $column)
            {
                //here you can set your conditions using find_in_set mysql condtions
                return $this;
            }
}
```

Comment: How do I apply it in ui-component grid ?

Comment: @Priyank did you figure it out? how to add condition filter to ui-component grid?