# Magento 2 : How to use filter call back in magento 2 admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, callback

How to use filter condition call back in Magento 2 in PHP Grid as we where using in Magento 1 previously like :

```
'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_customFilterCallBack')
```

Comment: you can check this refrence url:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139980/magento-2-filter-condition-callback

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'position',
    [
        'header' => __({{label}}),
        'name' => 'position',
        'type' => {{field type}},                
        'index' => 'position',               
        'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_customFilterCallBack']
    ]
);   



protected function _customFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
{
//Put your logic here..!!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best example you can find for filter call back is in magento core

you can see here magento uses filter call back `vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Grid.php`

I can shortly give you what code is there and you can see rest of the things in that file

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn(
        'store_id',
        [
            'header' => __('Store View'),
            'index' => 'store_id',
            'type' => 'store',
            'store_all' => true,
            'store_view' => true,
            'sortable' => false,
            'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_filterStoreCondition']
        ]
    );
}

protected function _filterStoreCondition($collection, \Magento\Framework\DataObject $column)
{
    if (!($value = $column->getFilter()->getValue())) {
        return;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($value);
}
```